# Lizard Alien and Cadet Boy

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space

I'm trying to find the book that is about a boy and a lizard-alien. The lizard-alien can only survive if it lives on the skin of its host as a tattoo and can only be away from its host for a set period of time before he fades. The lizard-alien is a guardian of some sort and lives by a code.

I forget what the book is about exactly. I only remember it is set in space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SF Series where Dragon looking creature that's a tattoo on the boy's body](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110953/sf-series-where-dragon-looking-creature-thats-a-tattoo-on-the-boys-body)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - IIRC our policy is to only close Story ID questions as dupes if they have accepted answers.

Answer (score 4):

### This is [*Dragon and Thief*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765342723), by Timothy Zahn

[image]

It could also be some other book in the Dragonback series.

This is a book about a boy who acquires a dragon-like alien that can become a tattoo.

> As the rest of his body reached Polphir’s, each part altered from
>   three-dimensional to two-dimensional form as it flowed onto his host’s
>   body. A split second later the transformation was complete, leaving
>   Draycos stretched like a living tattoo across Polphir’s back and legs
>   and arms.

Indeed, the dragon will die if it is too long away from a host:

> “After six hours had passed, I would die,” Draycos said softly “But I
>   am a warrior of the K’da. I will not force myself upon you if you do
>   not wish it.

Incidentally, this also demonstrates that Draycos lives by a code, as mentioned in the question.

Similarly:

> Jack was his host, and there was a high debt of honor between a K’da
>   warrior and his host.