# SciFi with Teenage Con Artist and draco-alien 2D ally?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

In the late 2000s, I remember reading a series about a teenage con-artist boy (maybe named Jack?) who teamed up with this dragon like alien who could body-jump aka turn into 2D tattoo on his skin. The draco alien was an advance scout of his species looking for a new safe world in Jack's galaxy, but was shot down by the enemy tentacle aliens with an "instant death" ray. Jack was an orphan with his own space ship, and a dead con-artist uncle who taught him all his tricks. Together, they adventured through space trying to find the enemy aliens and Jacks mysterious enemies (who killed his parents) and save the draco's species.

Does anyone remember what this series was? I haven't been able to google-fu the series.
Thanks!

Comment: Could be marked as a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110953/sf-series-where-dragon-looking-creature-thats-a-tattoo-on-the-boys-body/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably Timothy Zahn's [*Dragonback*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11467) series, starting with [*Dragon and Thief*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?23824) (2003) about a boy, Jack Morgan who discovers an alien, Draycos, who adopts Jack as his host and lives on him as a kind of living tattoo.

The plot summary of the first book on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/216445.Dragon_and_Thief) says:

> Jack Morgan has a dragon on his back - literally. The warrior K'da species are symbiotes, can only live six hours without their humanoid host. Draycos is the sole survivor of the three ships destroyed scouting for their refugees, and Jack is the only possible choice. They may be an odd couple, but together they're more than the sum of their parts. They are destined to travel far and wide, facing many perils - human, alien, and other, as they seek justice and safety - Jack for himself, and Draycos for his people.

Jack isn't actually a criminal himself, but he was framed for a crime and his uncle Virgil *was* a criminal who wanted Jack to be like him.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this is the series I was looking for!